# How can change header text in post careate/edit form

Tags: posts, customization

How can change header text in post careate/edit form  based on some query string params ?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the text that currently says "Add New Post" or are you trying to automatically fill in the Post Title itself?

Comment: I want to change  "Add New Post"  text dynamically